# Dynamic values for qSin and qCos giving error

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux

I was developing a QT application in embedded-qt-4.8.5 for drawing a circle with two lines inside that starting from the origin as shown in the figure.
The first line will be from origin to its right side towards circle. Second line will be at angle "angle" from the first line in anticlockwise direction. See figure for clarification.

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxpjs.png)

The code I used is

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Dialog dialog;
    dialog.setMinimumHeight(725);
    dialog.setMinimumWidth(1000);

    dialog.showMaximized();
    dialog.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include <QtDebug>

#include "dialog.h"
Dialog::Dialog()
{
    drawCircle =0;
    main_widget = new QWidget;
    menu_layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    circleRadiusText =new QTextEdit("");
    circleRadiusText->setFixedHeight(30);
    circleRadiusText->setFixedWidth(130);

    QPushButton *submitButton = new QPushButton("OK");
    submitButton->setFixedWidth(300);

    menu_layout->addWidget(circleRadiusText);
    menu_layout->addWidget(submitButton);
    setLayout(menu_layout);

    QObject::connect(submitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(draw_Circle()));

}
void Dialog::draw_Circle()
{

    angle =  circleRadiusText->toPlainText().toInt();

    drawCircle =1;
    update();
}
```

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QAction;
class QDialogButtonBox;
class QGroupBox;
class QLineEdit;
class QMenuBar;
class QPushButton;
class QTextEdit;
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QString>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <qmath.h>

QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog();

private slots:
    void draw_Circle();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
    {
        if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Q)
        {
            qApp->exit();
        }
    }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QPainter Painter(this);
        Painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true) ;
        if (drawCircle ==1)
            {
                int x1,y1,x2,y2;
                x1 =100;
                y1 = 100;
                x2 = 400;
                y2 = 400;
                int midx = 300;
                int midy = 300;
                int radius = 200;

                qDebug()<< angle;
                Painter.setBrush(QColor(Qt::white));
                Painter.drawEllipse(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                Painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(Qt::black)));

                Painter.drawLine(midx, midy, midx+radius, midy);
                Painter.drawLine(midx, midy, midx+(radius*qCos(angle*3.14/180)),midy+(radius*qSin(angle*3.14/180))); // Only working in PC
            }
     }
public:
        QWidget *main_widget;
        QTextEdit *circleRadiusText;
        QVBoxLayout *menu_layout;
        int angle;
        int drawCircle;

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

But while drawing second line I'm getting a run time error...
I have commented the instruction for drawing second line and checked. The first line is drawing correctly. The angle value is reading from a QTextEdit and the value of angle after converting from QTextEdit to integer is also correct. 
The same code works fine on QT Creator in PC.

> Alignment trap: not handling instruction ed840a00 at [<764c58cc>]
>
> Unhandled fault: alignment exception (0x801) at 0x3fc8f5c3

If I gave the angle value as static it'll draw the lines without any error. That is,

```
int angle1 = 100;
Painter.drawLine(midx, midy, midx+(radius*qCos(angle1*3.14/180)), midy+(radius*qSin(angle1*3.14/180)));
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should calculate your values before drawing the line. Not only helps that with debugging, but also increases readability.

Comment: The same thing I have tried. But the values which I got after calculating is wrong. That problem occurs only when I gave value dynamically. If its statically, like angle1 in above code then its giving proper answer.

Comment: Export the cos and sin value out, like `const double conversionRate = 3.14/180; const double convertedAngle = angle*conversionRate; const double cosValue = qCos(convertedAngle);  const double sinValue(convertedAngle)`. and check if all those values are correct, as unintended conversion from double to int might drop information. Also, it makes the code much more readable.

Comment: I tried like this

`const double conversionRate = 3.14/180;`  
`qDebug()<<conversionRate;  
const double convertedAngle = angle*conversionRate;  
qDebug()<<convertedAngle;  
const double cosValue = qCos(convertedAngle);  
qDebug()<<cosValue;  
const double sinValue = qSin(convertedAngle);  
qDebug()<<sinValue;`


But the output I'm getting is some thing junk values and a segmentation fault also.

Comment: Well, then try to understand those junk values and maybe it will solve your original issue.

Comment: I found the issue. It was my mistake and not related to qt. I was using a different cross compiler for compiling my qt. When I changed the cross compiler it gave proper output. Thanks for your suggestions. But still I wounder it gave wrong output only for qsin and qcos calculations.